# Employee table - hierarchy with some caveats

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've got an issue with a sort of standard employee table. In my example I have done self joins to the source however I don't get the end structure that I would like.

The hierarchy is a few levels up.

In a simple form the code is like:

```
select e.employee_name
    ,   e.teamlead_name
    ,   e1.teamlead_name 'manager_name'
    ,   e2.teamlead_name 'senior_manager_name'
    ,   e3.teamlead_name 'director_name'
from employees e

left join employees e1 on
    e.teamlead_id = e1.employee_id

left join employees e2 on
    e1.teamlead_id = e2.employee_id

left join employees e3 on
    e2.teamlead_id = e3.employee_id
```

This gives me a good base but the director for example will become a teamlead when one of their direct reports is listed as a employee. Also get the same issue but for managers and senior managers as well where they won't be at level you would expect. This wouldn't be an issue except for reporting when the hierarchy isn't what the end users expect as the director, senior managers and managers fall into all the levels on the hierarchy.

I would prefer in this instance for the data to be structured as below.

Currently is like this

```
employee_name director_name null null null
```

Would like this

```
employee_name null null null director_name
```

I've kind of found a way around the issue by using case statements however isn't  exactly the cleanest way of doing it and I'm hoping there is a nicer way of doing it.

To get the director aligned properly it's easier as there is nobody above them so I have done something like the below which works and always aligns the director to the correct spot then I separately use a nullif when to null out the other columns this is done with a CTE.

```
concat (e3.teamlead_name, 
case when e1.teamlead_name is null 
    and e2.teamlead_name is null
    and e3.teamlead_name is null
then e.teamlead_name end,

case when e2.teamlead_name is null
    and e3.teamlead_name is null
then e1.teamlead_name end,

case when e3.teamlead_name is null
then e2.teamlead_name end) 'director_name'
```

The director isn't an employee in this system, they only exist a teamleader and above.

I think I could probably resolve and eventually get everything aligned as they want it doing it as per the above but surely there is a much better way of doing this? Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I would write this as three CTEs (Common Table Expressions) to get emp_Level+1, emp_level+2 and emp_level+3 and I would include the management level descriptor in the CTE.

I would then UNION together the three CTEs to provide a combined data set with up to 3 records per employee and then create a dynamic pivot table based on the management level descriptions.  You should be able to Google all of these processes, but come back with your code if you get stuck.

It really depends on what you are going to do with the data once you have it.  It may make more sense to let the reporting tool do the pivoting, especially if you are going to use SSRS or Excel